# NumberFormatter for decimal place in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have the following code which works fine except keeping 0 after decimal. The goal is to format the user input as user types on Textfield

```
MyClass {
     static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
         let formatter = NumberFormatter()
         formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
         formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
         formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
         return formatter
     }()
} 
extension Double {
     func formatted() -> String{
         return MyClass.amountFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? "0"
     }
 }
```

This gives me the below output

1. 1256.formatted - 1,256
2. 1256.00.formatted - 1,256 (Need to retain 0 after decimal, **desired result  - 1,256.00**)
3. 1256.05.formatted - 1,256.05
4. 1256.80.formatted - 1,256.8 (Need to retain 0 after decimal, **desired result 1,256.80**)
5. 1256.5789847.formatted - 1,256.57

How to achieve the desired output

Comment: But `1256` and `1256.00` are the same value. How are you supposed to know that one gets no decimals and the other should show two?

Comment: Based on user input. I need to format the textfield text as user types in. So user should be able to type 1256.00. With the current formatting logic, whenever user inputs 125,6.0 it converts it to 1,256 , So user is never able to input numbers like 1256.0X

Comment: That information needs to be in your question. So your actual goal is to format a string being entered by the user. That’s very different from the question you are currently asking.

Comment: @rmaddy my apologies for the confusion. Yes i need to format string entered by the user